# tar directory incl root files as non-root

Tags: tar

I would like to tar an directory with a non-root user. But in this directory are also files with root permissions.

Example:

```
foo@bar:~ $ ls -l tmp/
insgesamt 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 foo  foo  6 Mär 16 08:38 test.1
-rw------- 1 root root 6 Mär 16 08:38 test.2
```

If I run tar-command as "foo" user, I received an error: "Permission denied".
Example:

```
foo@bar:~ $ tar -czf --preserve-permissions test.tar.gz ./tmp
tar: tmp/test.2: function open failed. Permission denied.
```

How can I solve this permission issue? If possible, I prefer do use a non-root user.

Comment: If you could, you would have found a serious security bug in Linux ...

Comment: I thought so. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can not.**

To `tar` a file, you need to read it. However, only `root` is allowed to **read** and write the file. (permissions are `rw-------` / `600`).

```
owner = rw-
group = ---
others = ---
```

Owner is `root`, `foo` is likely *others*.

---

You could read the file with user `foo` after changing permissions:

```bsh
# give read permission (+r) to others (o) 
sudo chmod o+r ./tmp/test.2
```

or

```bsh
# Set specific permissions value -> 6=rw- 4=r--
sudo chmod 644 ./tmp/test.2
```

or by changing owner to `foo`:

```bsh
sudo chown foo: ./tmp/test.2
```

If your user is not a `sudoer` on that machine, you could still do this from a root console or from a live system.

---

Then, your command should work fine without problems:

```
foo@bar:~ $ tar -czf --preserve-permissions test.tar.gz ./tmp
```